# How to display server Log in Primefaces Log Component

Tags: primefaces, log4j

I see it is possible in the docs but can't seem to find a way of implementing it.

> Log API is also available via global PrimeFaces object in case you’d
> like to use the log component to display your logs.

[Using Primefaces 6.2](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_2.pdf)

[Primefaces Log Component](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/log.xhtml)

Binding Log4J to `<p:log id="log" />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything in @Kukeltje's answer is true.

Still, if your end-game is to see your server logs in the front-end of your JSF app, I would do the following:

1. Add a DB appender to your logging framework so that all logs are written to the database.
   https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender
   https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#DBAppender
2. Create a jsf datatable to view the logs in. https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml

Initially, I would recommend that you filter the logs when retrieving it from the DB to only show the newest ones in the table, otherwise the table might be too big to load within a reasonable time. As a permanent solution, I would recommend that you implement the LazyDataModel
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml

It can be very handy to be able to filter and /or sort by log severity, time, and all the fields supported by by your logging framework.

Non related: Splunk has a universal forwarder utility that can submit a copy of your logs to a splunk server so that you can analyze your logs in near realtime. https://www.splunk.com/en_us/download/universal-forwarder.html

Comment: the answer referred in the first line seems to be not here anymore, can you please provide some info as to what it was?

Answer (score 0):

hope it is not too late.
I figured it out. From your Java Bean, you can use the PrimeFaces obj to execute a javascript in that way you can use for example the Primefaces.info('your log message'); to print in your log.

**example function:**

```
public void sendMessageToLog(int count) {
        String text = "PrimeFaces.info('Testing Logger #" + count + "');";
        PrimeFaces pf = PrimeFaces.current();
        pf.executeScript(text); // This will execute the script in your page
    }
```